# Optimising Postgresql Queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have two tables and i have to query my postgresql database. The table 1 has about 140 million records and table 2 has around 50 million records of the following.

the table 1 has the following structure:

```
tr_id bigint NOT NULL, # this is the primary key
query_id numeric(20,0),       # indexed column
descrip_id numeric(20,0)      # indexed column
```

and table 2 has the following structure

```
query_pk  bigint # this is the primary key
query_id  numeric(20,0)    # indexed column
query_token numeric(20,0)
```

The sample db of table1 would be

```
1 25 96
2 28 97
3 27 98
4 26 99
```

The sample db of table2 would be

```
 1 25 9554
 2 25 9456
 3 25 9785
 4 25 9514
 5 26 7412
 6 26 7433
 7 27 545
 8 27 5789
 9 27 1566
10 28 122
11 28 1456
```

I am preferring queries in which i would be able to query in blocks of tr_id. In range of 10,000 as this is my requirement.

I would like to get output in the following manner

```
25  {9554,9456,9785,9514}
26  {7412,7433}
27  {545,5789,1566}
28  {122,1456}
```

I tried in the following manner

```
select query_id, 
       array_agg(query_token) 
from sch.table2 
where query_id in (select query_id 
                   from sch.table1 
                   where tr_id between 90001 and 100000) 
group by query_id
```

I am performing the following query which takes about 121346 ms and when some 4 such queries are fired it still takes longer time. Can you please help me to optimise the same.

I have a machine which runs on windows 7 with i7 2nd gen proc with 8GB of RAM.

The following is my postgresql configuration

```
shared_buffers = 1GB    
effective_cache_size = 5000MB
work_mem = 2000MB
```

What should I do to optimise it.

Thanks

EDIT : it would be great if the results ordered according to the following format

```
25  {9554,9456,9785,9514}
28  {122,1456}
27  {545,5789,1566}
26  {7412,7433}
```

ie according to the order of the queryid  present in table1 ordered by tr_id. If this is computationally expensive may be in the client code i would try to optimise it. But I am not sure how efficient it would be.

Thanks

Comment: Add an `EXPLAIN` in front of your query, and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: EXPLAIN ANALYZE is even better, shows also the time (in ms) spend. "work_mem = 2000MB" is dangerous, a single query can eat all your RAM (you just have 8GB) and crash. 10MB is a good and safe starting point.

Comment: Is this a dedicated database server? I.e., PostgreSQL can use most of the resources?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.It is not a dedicated database server however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Query

I expect a `JOIN` to be much faster that the `IN` condition you have presently:

```
SELECT t2.query_id
      ,array_agg(t2.query_token) AS tokens
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 USING (query_id)
WHERE  t1.tr_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
GROUP  BY t1.tr_id, t2.query_id
ORDER  BY t1.tr_id;
```

This also sorts the results as requested. `query_token` remains unsorted per `query_id`.

#### Indexes

Obviously you need indexes on `t1.tr_id` and `t2.query_id`.
You obviously have that one already:

```
CREATE INDEX t2_query_id_idx ON t2 (query_id);
```

A multicolumn index on `t1` may improve performance (you'll have to test):

```
CREATE INDEX t1_tr_id_query_id_idx ON t1 (tr_id, query_id);
```

#### Server configuration

If this is a dedicated database server, you can raise the setting for `effective_cache_size` some more.

@Frank already gave advise on `work_mem`. I quote [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM):

> Note that for a complex query, several sort or hash operations might
>   be running in parallel; each operation will be allowed to use as much
>   memory as this value specifies before it starts to write data into
>   temporary files. Also, several running sessions could be doing such
>   operations concurrently. Therefore, the total memory used could be
>   many times the value of work_mem;

It should be just big enough to be able to sort your queries in RAM. 10 MB is more than plenty to hold 10000 of your rows at a time. Set it higher, if you have queries that need more at a time.

With 8 GB on a dedicated database server, I would be tempted to set `shared_buffers` to at least 2 GB.

```
shared_buffers = 2GB    
effective_cache_size = 7000MB
work_mem = 10MB
```

More advice on [performance tuning in the Postgres Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization).

Comment: It is not a dedicated server. I will incorporate all of them except the cache size which i will set a bit lower.Thanks for your suggestiosn